# Need Help Structuring a Page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

*My failed attempt is at* http://jsfiddle.net/NZtc4/

I'm trying to make a web app page that displays the following page, regardless of screen size.

`[Toolbar]`
`[ Image ]`
`[img][img][img]` <-- This row should be scrollable <-> (draggable)

- The toolbar is the jquery mobile one.
- The image should be 67% of the remaining height and 100% width.
- The imgs should be 50% width of the page and be the remaining height. (Two whole images equivalent shown at any given time.)
- Any number of imgs >2.

  (All images will be anchors, but this is beyond the scope of the question.)

The page should be seamless; i.e. no gaps between elements.

Answer is demonstration or explanation of implementation of described page.

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML line break would be interpreted as a space if your elements are `inline-block`. in order to remove this gap you need to add `font-size:0`. As a side effect this requires you to provide provide font-size for elements that actually contain text. (otherwise they won't show any text). in CSS3 you can use `font-size:1rem` to set the font-size to the one of body (root).

for the bottom scroller, you don't need to specify `width`, instead you need `white-space:nowrap` so your elements appear on same row.

see edited example: http://jsfiddle.net/NZtc4/2/

Comment: The document still exceeds the screen, resulting in scrolling needed.